# How is using AND keyword different from using "joins" [explicitly] in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

Do we really need the keyword join for selecting column wise result sets or AND conditions are (according to situation) sufficient? What's the difference in using inner join and AND keyword?

Comment: In most cases: apples and oranges.

Comment: Do you mean to ask what the difference is between putting a conditional in the WHERE clause and putting it in the ON clause of a join statement?

Answer (score 1):

The two are completely different.

`AND` narrows your result set.

`INNER JOIN` lets you cross-reference related tables based on a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

They are completely different.

AND allows you to specify more than one condition within a single clause. For example, `select * from table where col1=1 and col2=0` puts two conditions on a single WHERE clause, affecting which records you get from a single table.

INNER JOIN allows you to combine the columns from one table with the columns from another table. It matches up rows based on the condition you provide in the ON clause.